# SwiftUI Discovering Ethernet Printer issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, printing

please can someone give me directions on how to discover and connect ethernet cabled thermal receipt printer.
I currently bought Gprinter (there's limited SDK doc and its very old), information as below.
this printer has its own wifi, once I connected to this printer's remote wifi I am able to print data HOWEVER if connected to this remote wifi, my app won't have internet abilities to upload documents to firebase due to no internet.
code used to send to this printer's remote wifi.

it has a ethernet socket and I want it to become a network printer so my apps can access it and print the tickets.
many thanks in advance

```
   var address : String
    var port : Int
    var task : URLSessionStreamTask!
    var command = Printer()
    init(host:String,port:Int) {
        print("init")
        self.address = host
        self.port = port
        setupConnection()
    }
    
    func setupConnection() {
        print("setup")
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        task = session.streamTask(withHostName: address, port: port)
        self.task.resume()
    }
    
    func send(data:NSData){
        self.task.write(data as Data, timeout: 5.0) { error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Data Sent")
            } else {
                print("Noe")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sendCommand(_ data: Data){
        send(data: data as NSData)
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be able to reconfigure the printer to connect to an existing wifi network. You may also need to reconfigure it to use the cabled port, or it may just use DHCP on the cabled port; try connecting an Ethernet cable and turn on the printer holding down the feed button to get the configuration report. Some printers have an inbuilt web page for configuration while others may need some config software.

Comment: thank you very much buddy, you have helped me levelled up.  i followed your direction, managed to get software from manufacture to configure the IP address(why changed the IP address which I don't know), I just followed it and it worked. I have successfully printed ticket from my app. many thanks